# gnuplot: plot image without white border

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot image data using gnuplot, without any border, tics, etc. Just the image. Unfortunately, gnuplot always draws the bottom line white. Here is an example of what should result in an entirely black 3x3 pixel image:

```
set term png size 3,3
set out 'test.png'


set xrange [0:2]
set yrange [0:2]
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set size ratio -1
unset xtics
unset ytics
set border 0
unset key

p '-' w rgbimage
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0
1 2 0 0 0
2 2 0 0 0
e
```

The result is a picture with one white line and 2 black pixel lines:

[image]

Here is a magnified screenshot with a gray frame of the image viewer:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

I am using gnuplot 5.0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I realize this does not help you much, but given that gnuplot is designed for plotting charts, I think that attempting to plot to a 3x3 image is a misuse of the software and does not suit it's intentions.

Comment: I just tried this, and an image of size 7x7 appears to be the minimum size that does not leave a residual white line. Consider increasing your image size.

Comment: The 3x3 image is an example to demonstrate the effect, to make it as simple as possible. The image itself shows scientific data, a vector field of typically 400x80 pixels size. I like gnuplot because I can also add arrows and save it as a vector graphics, e.g., pdf. If you know any other software that does this job, please let me know.

Comment: Here you find the data I would like to plot: http://www.filedropper.com/testdata It is 400x80 px large and gnuplot draws a white pixel line in the bottom. Most importantly, this line comes at a loss of the top pixel line.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the [Gnuplot info mailinglist](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/gnuplot-info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having a 3px times 3px image is not a proper use case. Of course, representing a 3x3 data matrix is perfectly valid!

Seems, like there are some problems when plotting pixel-based data with some terminals. Since you said, that in the end you want to have a vector image (which would in any case affect only some arrows you draw on top of the pixel-data), I had a look at some vector formats only, using your example `testdata.dat` and the script `testdata.gp`

```
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set margins 0,0,0,0
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
unset key

p 'testdata.dat' w rgbimage
```

- `pdfcairo` doesn't work, has some boundary artifacts.
- `postscript` works fine, I used

  ```
  set terminal postscript eps level3 size 8cm,1.6cm
  set output 'testdata.eps'
  load 'testdata.gp'
  set output
  system('epstopdf testdata.eps')
  ```
- `tikz` works fine as well:

  ```
  set terminal tikz standalone externalimages size 8cm,1.6cm
  set output 'testdata.tex'
  load 'testdata.gp'
  set output
  system('pdflatex testdata.tex')
  ```
- `svg` works fine:

  ```
  set terminal svg standalone size 800,160
  set output 'testdata.svg'
  load 'testdata.gp'
  ```

I don't know yet, what the actual problem with the cairo terminals is.

Comment: Thank you for these workarounds. With svg, the pixel structure of the image is lost, which is problematic for my data. However, eps works very well.

Comment: For SVG the pixel structure shouldn't be lost, that is probably an artifact of your viewer. For svg a PNG is generated which is linked to (name `gp_image...png`)

Comment: Okay, you are right. It just behaves differently than the png terminal when I set the resolution higher than the number of data points in the image. I used 4x more pixels per dimension to get sharp arrows, and the svg terminal made an interpolation to determine the value of the additional pixels. Actually a very nice feature if you know how to use it.